# Play image sequence using Qt QMainWindow

Tags: image, qt, sequence, playback

I have an image sequence rendered out. which I want to payback in a simple QMainWindow or QDialog. This is what I have sofar. It loads the images into the qlabel, but I cant see the label being updated, its just show the last loaded image, and nothing in between. 
Maybe someone knows something?

```
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui
import shiboken
import maya.OpenMayaUI as apiUI
import time

def getMayaWindow():
    """
    Get the main Maya window as a QtGui.QMainWindow instance
    @return: QtGui.QMainWindow instance of the top level Maya windows
    """
    ptr = apiUI.MQtUtil.mainWindow()
    if ptr is not None:
        return shiboken.wrapInstance(long(ptr), QtGui.QWidget)


class Viewer(QtGui.QMainWindow):

def __init__(self, parent = getMayaWindow()):
    super(Viewer, self).__init__(parent)
    self.setGeometry(400, 600, 400, 300)  
    self.setUi()   

def setUi(self):
    self.label = QtGui.QLabel()
    self.setCentralWidget(self.label)

def showUi(self):
    self.show()

def loadImage(self, path):
    self.label.clear()
    image = QtGui.QImage(path)
    pp = QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(image)
    self.label.setPixmap(pp.scaled(
            self.label.size(),
            QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio,
            QtCore.Qt.SmoothTransformation))

x = Viewer()
x.showUi()
for i in range(1, 11):    
    x.loadImage("C://anim%03d.png" % i)
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

Comment: Not familiar with python, but my C++ eyes tells me that you change pixmaps in loop and sleep all GUI thread. It is not correct. Try to use QTimer for this purpose, signal timeout, create slot and change pixmaps in this slot. Point me if I don't right or if this helped you.

Comment: Its blocking the GUI. I just tried qLabel.repaint() which now plays back the sequence. But still blocks the GUI. 
I will try the QTimer to see if it still blocks the ui

Comment: No QTimer will not block GUI, I posted this as answer because it is a solution, also I added explanation why it will not block GUI thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You change pixmaps in loop and sleep (stop) all `GUI` thread, that's why your `GUI` freeze.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/time_sleep.htm

It is not correct. `qLabel.repaint()` it is bad solution because it still blocks `GUI`. Of course you can use `processEvents` but it is bad approach too.

You should use `QTimer` for this purpose, use `timeout()` signal, create slot and change pixmaps in this slot. In this case your `GUI` will not be blocked because `QTimer` works asynchronously and images will be successfuly changed.

Same code with loop and `sleep` can help you only when this code will execute in another thread (multi threading) but it is not necessary because there is special class `QTimer`.